# Use Apache as an HTTP proxy for SMB/CIFS links (Bonus points for Synology solution)

Tags: apache-2.2, server-message-block

Am I doing this right? Situation:

- a file server (`FILE_SERVER`) containing a share with a bunch of documents.

  - users can access files on the share either with

    - `afp://FILE_SERVER/SHARE/path/to/doc`
    - `\\FILE_SERVER\SHARE\path\to\doc`
- users want to send links to these files via email
- users want to post links to these files in a wiki (TWiki)
- I have an Apache Server to muck around with (running on a Synology DS2011+)

**Problem is**: There is no canonical way to link to files that works on all combinations of (osx, windows) x (chrome, safari, ie, firefox).

**Solution?** I'd like to configure the apache server to serve these documents, if they are presented in a nice form. Something like:

```
`http://WEB_SERVER/SHARE/path/to/doc`
```

I am able to mount the SMB share as a folder on the Synology server if that helps, but I'm a little worried about security here.

**Questions**:

- should I just mount the share and serve it up? how? (I'm getting a 403, which checks out, since the user is `admin`, uh, I'm in for trouble here...)
- How to provide authorization?

  - I'd like users to have to provide the same credentials they would use if they were connecting to the network drive in Windows Explorer / Finder

Comment: Did you manage to make this work ? Would you be kind to share the steps ?

Comment: @Pranav, this was nine years ago. I just gave up on using server shares instead: Anything worth linking to is either on GitHub or some kind of cloud solution. If I were to talk to my past self, I'd probably suggest returning a "302 Found" and rewriting the link based on the (assumed) os of the user.